# How to embed SVG tag inside google wave gadget?

Tags: svg, google-wave, google-gadget

I'm creating a google wave gadget that needs to embed SVG.
I don't want to do  because that means I need to generate separate svg file and store somewhere on the web.

I would like to simply add  inside the Google Wave Gadget.

The person who created the [Canvas Gadget](http://wave-samples-gallery.appspot.com/about_app?app_id=18016) ([Source Code](http://ichikawa-public.appspot.com/wave/canvas/canvas.xml)) has done this, but I can't figure out what he did to get this work. When I simply add  tags inside the gadget, the browsers ignore the tag and anything inside the svg element.

Answer (score 0):

From what i have seen you cannot embed the image. What can be done is to make a base64 encoded version of the graphic and embed that.

Answer (score 0):

The Canvas Gadget you linked to uses [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) to render dynamically render SVG. You should look into using that within yours, too:

http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html